# Which version Of UmbracoCMS works on VS2010 .net framework 4.0

Tags: visual-studio-2010, umbraco

I'm new to using UmbracoCMS. I installed version 7.1.1 from nuGet but it seems that it needs framework 4.5

Can you help me with which version of UmbracoCMS would work on VS2010 framework 4.0?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes Umbraco 7 uses 4.5 all **versions of 6** or earlier uses 4.0

Lates version which did not uses 4.5 is ***v6.1.6***

Nuget Command is

```
 Install-Package UmbracoCms -Version 6.1.6
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you downlod v6.1.6, which uses .NET 4.0: http://our.umbraco.org/contribute/releases/616